# Dynamic scaling with SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, spring-jms

I am currently looking to implement JMS message consumers using spring wrappers.

After reading the JMS documentation it seems to me that the way to go ahead would be to adopt the asynchronous message delivery model, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnceh/index.html where the JMS provider would invoke the listener for message delivery instead polling.

However `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, the spring wrapper which implements the asynchronous message delivery model doesn't seem to support dynamic scaling of listener instances.

`DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, the spring wrapper which implements the synchronous message delivery model seems to support dynamic scaling.

I wish to understand this. I can't seem to find any explanation in either spring or JMS documents.